# npm i failed because of dependency in private registry

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-publish, npm-package, github-package-registry

I published a private npm package for internal usage (to npm.pkg.github.com).

then i created another private npm package in the same registry which uses the first private package as a dependency. all the other packages are from the default npm registry.

when I try to install the second npm package to a new project, the install fails, because npm i tries to install the dependency (my first private package) from the default npm registry (i assume the .npmrc of my package gets ignored)

how can i fix that ?

what i have tried so far:

- install the dependency package before adding the second package (still 404 after the second step)

Answer (score 0):

Use the information from the npmrc file (where you scope the package to a specific registry) in your global .npmrc file on the device you want to install the private dependency package

Comment: Could you add a little more detail about how the OP should go about doing that?